# CakePHP Auth $this->Auth->allow('display')

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have a problem showing static pages to non-authenticated users in my app.

I'm using cake 2.1 and my AppController.php is like this:

```
App::uses('Controller','Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('display');
    }
}
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but the `display` action is not part of the `AppController`. It belongs to the `PagesController`instead.

Try adding this logic to the `PagesController` located under `app/Controllers/PagesController.php`. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in PagesController

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('display');
}
```

At least it worked for me. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Appcontroller.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {

...
  public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    $this->set('loggedUser', $this->Auth->user());

    $this->loadModel('Evento');
    $this->set('eventos', $this->Evento->find('all'));
  }

}
```

PagesController.php

```
class PagesController extends AppController {

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    // Allow users to register and logout.
    $this->Auth->allow('display');
}
 ...
```